# How to use migrate process plugin concat on multiple values?

Tags: 8, migrations, plugins

I am trying to import from a csv that has multiple files in the same column, e.g.

```
title,gallery,tag
node1,img1.jpg|img2.jpg|img3.jpg,2
node2,img4.jpg,2
node3,img5.jpg|img6.jpg,3
```

I need to prepend the path to these file names to get something of the form `/path/to/file/img4.jpg`.

I have written a process pipeline similar to the following (which doesn't work):

```
source:
  constants:
    file_source: '/import/images/'
    file_destination: '/path/to/file/'
process:
  title: title
  field_gallery:
    -
      plugin: explode
      source: gallery
      delimiter: '|'
    -
      plugin: concat
      source:
        - constants/file_source
        -
    -
      plugin: image_import
      destination: constants/file_destination
```

The failure comes because the Concat plugin implodes the array containing a string and an array to give an output in the form `/path/to/file/Array`.

I suspect there is a process plugin that I can insert between explode and concat that will solve this, but I can't work out what it is.

I have tried combinations of the plugins `single_value` and `multiple_values` from the Migrate Plus module, but that has not worked either.

For now I have written a custom process plugin to replace concat, but I would prefer a pipeline using pre-existing plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with `concat` in a single pipe, because you need to define two sources for concat, and AFAIK you can't fill the source partly with the result from the previous section and partly with a completely new value.

Workaround: Use the [str_replace](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/migrate_plus/blob/HEAD/src/Plugin/migrate/process/StrReplace.php) plugin  instead, which is a wrapper for PHP's [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php).

`preg_replace` will detect if `source` respectively `$subject` is an string or an array. If the `$subject` is an array, all elements will be updated, so you can replace all beginnings of a string `^` with `/some/path/`

Something like this:

```
  field_gallery:
    -
      plugin: str_replace
      regex: true
      source: gallery
      search: '/^/'
      replace: '/some/path/'
```

(Note that the slashes in `search` are not path delimiters, they are the enclosing symbol for the regex pattern)

Comment: Thanks @Hudri, I definitely prefer using the `str_replace` process plugin over a custom plugin. Can you think of a way to use a source constant, i.e. `constants/file_source` rather than hard-coding the value of `replace` to `'/some/path/'`?

Comment: Not really, this is by design of the Migrate module. Only the `source:` is treated like a reference, all other keys are config and used like a value.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the highlights of the process plugin I wrote, in case anyone is interested in a custom solution:

```
class Prepend extends ProcessPluginBase {

  public function transform($value, MigrateExecutableInterface $migrate_executable, Row $row, $destination_property) {
    $return = [];
    foreach ($value as $item) {
      $return[] = implode($item);
    }
    return $return;
  }

  public function multiple() {
    return TRUE;
  }

}
```

Note: an important difference between this and the `concat` process plugin is the addition of the `multiple()` function that returns TRUE.

It can be used as follows:

```
field_gallery:
  -
    plugin: explode
    source: gallery_images
    delimiter: '|'
  -
    plugin: prepend
    source:
      - constants/file_source
      -
  -
    plugin: image_import
    destination: constants/file_destination
    uid: '@uid'
    skip_on_missing_source: true
```

**EDIT**: FWIW I have chosen to use the solution suggested by @Hudri.