# Migrating an array of values into multiple entities

Tags: migrations, 9

I'm using migrate/migrate_plus modules to import CSV files and generate entities.

One of the columns in the CSV can contain multiple values like 1|2|3, which I'm converting to an array using:

```
_jurisdictions:
  plugin: explode
  source: jurisdiction
  delimiter: "|"
```

I'm then using the array to generate taxonomy terms with this:

```
field_political_district:
  -
    plugin: entity_generate
    source: "@_jurisdictions"
    entity_type: taxonomy_term
    bundle: political_district
    bundle_key: vid
    value_key: name
    ignore_case: true
    values:
      field_display_name: ???
```

I'm stuck on two things:

- I want to append a constant value to each name so that the taxonomy term name becomes "1, XYZ" where XYZ comes from constants/ABC
- I want field_display_name to be the the value prefixed with "District "

Any thoughts on how to accomplish those two things?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use migrate process plugin concat on multiple values?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/307731/how-to-use-migrate-process-plugin-concat-on-multiple-values)

Comment: I played around with using str_replace, but it doesn't recognise constants, so if I set replace to constants/ABC I get the literal "constants/ABC". Also I'm not sure how I would use that in the second scenario of setting field_display_name.

Comment: Only the `source:` can contain a reference, all other keys are config and used by value. It might be *aesthetically pleasing* if provided with `constant/something`, but technically writing your string into `replace: 'foo'` is as hardcoded as writing it into `constants/something: 'foo'`

Comment: Yeah that's why I can't use str_replace. The constant is coming from a Deriver so is different depending on which csv is being processed.

Comment: EDIT: If you are using core version >9.2, you might create some crazy [callback with unpack_source](https://www.drupal.org/node/3205079)

Comment: Thanks, that's the way things were looking, just wanted to confirm there wasn't an out-of-the-box way.. I'll post my plugin as an answer when I'm done.

Comment: You might use the new v9.2 callback and create helper variables in your process section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the custom plugin I ended up writing:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\migrate\process;

use Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutableInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;
use Drupal\migrate_plus\Plugin\migrate\process\EntityGenerate;
use Drupal\migrate_plus\Plugin\migrate\process\EntityLookup;

/**
 * This plugin generates district entities within the process plugin.
 *
 * @MigrateProcessPlugin(
 *   id = "district_generate"
 * )
 *
 * @see EntityGenerate
 *
 * @code
 * process:
 *   field_political_district:
 *     plugin: district_generate
 *     source: jurisdiction
 *     district_set_name: constants/ABC
 *     district_set_value: "@_district_set"
 *     prefix: "District"
 *     ... other entityGenerate config
 * @endcode
 */
class DistrictGenerate extends EntityGenerate {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function transform($value, MigrateExecutableInterface $migrateExecutable, Row $row, $destinationProperty) {
    $this->row = $row;
    $this->migrateExecutable = $migrateExecutable;
    $name = $value;
    if (isset($this->configuration['district_set_name'])) {
      $suffix = $row->get($this->configuration['district_set_name']);
      $name = $name . ', ' . $suffix;
    }
    // Creates an entity if the lookup determines it doesn't exist.
    if (!($result = EntityLookup::transform($name, $migrateExecutable, $row, $destinationProperty))) {
      if (isset($this->configuration['district_set_value'])) {
        $this->configuration['values']['field_district_set'] = $this->configuration['district_set_value'];
      }
      $prefix = $this->configuration['prefix'] ?? 'District';
      $this->configuration['default_values']['field_display_name'] = $prefix . ' ' . $value;
      $result = $this->generateEntity($name);
    }
    return $result;
  }

}
```